# How can I find in VBA (MS Access) if user "confirmed" or "cancelled" the delete of the record in the implicit Access message box?

Tags: ms-access, confirm, reply

the user in my database is allowed to delete records. There are several events associated with the Form I am using: Delete, BeforeDelConfirm and AfterDelConfirm

Between BEFOREDELCONFIRM and AFTERDELCONFIRM there is a dialog box that asks the user the following question:
"You are about to delete 1 record(s). If you clock Yes, you won't be able to undo this Delete operation. Are you sure you want to delete these records?"   Yes / No

How can I find in AfterDelConfirm event in VBA what he selected ?

why I need this - I want to insert a deleted record into an Audit_Table. The trouble is that I need to insert it only if the user confirmed the delete. Thanks in advance

--------------   This saves the deleted record regardless of the user's choice   --------------

```
Dim Global_ModelKey As Integer      'used to store temporarily the ModelKey value 

Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
Global_ModelKey = Me.modelKey.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
'--- SQL command ---
sql = '<sql command>
'--- display message with the SQL command to check syntax ---
result = MsgBox(sql, vbOK, "SQL check", "", 1000)

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Global_ModelKey = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to consult the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.afterdelconfirm(even)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because explicit example available in MS documentation. Nothing unusual in this question.